# Transitioning between view controller, OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I am trying to write a single window timer application, where when the user presses the start button I want it to show another view controller with countdown etc. I'm also using story board in Xcode, where I have got a segue which connects the start button and the second view controller. However, there are only three different styles i.e. modal, sheet, and pop-over. I want to replace the first view controller the second one in the window. I cannot find a way to do that. I tried using a custom style for the segue, and in that use presentViewController: animator: method but I cannot figure out what to send as the argument for the animator:.

What is the simplest/proper way to transition from one view controller to the other in one window and vice versa?

Also in the storyboard when I select a view controller it shows an attribute called "Presentation" which can be multiple and single, what do those represent?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think the simplest way is that swapping `contentViewController` of `NSWindow`.

```
// in NSViewController's subclass
@IBAction func someAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let nextViewController = ... // instantiate from storyboard or elsewhere

    if let window = view.window where window.styleMask & NSFullScreenWindowMask > 0 {
        // adjust view size to current window
        nextViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, window.frame.width, window.frame.height)
    }

    view.window?.contentViewController = nextViewController
}
```

This is option #1.

If you want to use segue, create custom one and set it to segue class with identifier in IB.

```
class ReplaceSegue: NSStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        if let fromViewController = sourceController as? NSViewController {
            if let toViewController = destinationController as? NSViewController {
                // no animation.
                fromViewController.view.window?.contentViewController = toViewController
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is option #2.

Last option is using `presentViewController:animator:` of `NSViewController`. The code below is custom `NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator` for dissolve animation.

```
class ReplacePresentationAnimator: NSObject, NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator {
    func animatePresentationOfViewController(viewController: NSViewController, fromViewController: NSViewController) {
        if let window = fromViewController.view.window {
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in
                fromViewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 0
            }, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
                viewController.view.alphaValue = 0
                window.contentViewController = viewController
                viewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
            })
        }
    }

    func animateDismissalOfViewController(viewController: NSViewController, fromViewController: NSViewController) {
        if let window = viewController.view.window {
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in
                viewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 0
                }, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
                    fromViewController.view.alphaValue = 0
                    window.contentViewController = fromViewController
                    fromViewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
            })
        }        
    }
}
```

Then present VC like this.

```
@IBAction func replaceAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let nextViewController = ... // instantiate from storyboard or elsewhere
    presentViewController(nextViewController, animator: ReplacePresentationAnimator())
}
```

For dismissal, call `presentingViewController`'s `dismissViewController:` in the presented VC.

```
@IBAction func dismissAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    presentingViewController?.dismissViewController(self)    
}
```

**Swift4 Version**

```
class ReplacePresentationAnimator: NSObject, NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator {
func animatePresentation(of viewController: NSViewController, from fromViewController: NSViewController) {
    if let window = fromViewController.view.window {
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in
            fromViewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 0
        }, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
            viewController.view.alphaValue = 0
            window.contentViewController = viewController
            viewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
        })
    }
}

func animateDismissal(of viewController: NSViewController, from fromViewController: NSViewController) {
    if let window = viewController.view.window {
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in
            viewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 0
        }, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
            fromViewController.view.alphaValue = 0
            window.contentViewController = fromViewController
            fromViewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
        })
    }
}
```

}

Hope this help.

Comment: I found that option 1 didnt work in full screen mode

Comment: @jiminybob99 thanks for reporting!  I updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you have one parent view controller, you can assign child view controllers to it, and use the `transition` method. Example code, to be placed in viewDidLoad of the parent view controller:

```
if let firstController = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "firstController") as? NSViewController {
    firstController.view.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
    firstController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.addChild(firstController)
    self.view.addSubview(firstController.view)
}

if let secondController = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "secondController") as? NSViewController {
    self.addChild(secondController)
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    if let firstController = self.children.first, let secondController = self.children.last {
        self.transition(from: firstController, to: secondController, options: .crossfade, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

It's essential that the view of the first child controller is being added as sub view to the view of the parent controller, otherwise the `transition` method doesn't work.

In the example above, a storyboard is used with one main view controller (= self), one child view controller with storyboard ID "firstController', and another child view controller with storyboard ID "secondController'

Comment: Answering a question from three years ago. You really are a good samaritan not looking for that good old karma! I can’t test this because haven’t done iOS/macOS dev in three years but hopefully this will help others who are facing this problem now.

Comment: @user14492: I was actually searching for an answer myself. I saw that none of the examples in StackOverflow used the modern `transition` method, so I could not stop myself to compose an answer, after figuring out how the method actually works :)

Comment: thanks for your effort and sharing. I couldn’t actually figure that out back then. Good to know it was just me.